# How to "sync" FPS or performing an action at a certain fraction of each second

Tags: java

My goal is to create a statement that will call a method every 1/30 of a second (the actual number is a variable called `fileFPS`), and happening exactly 30 times per second.  I am having trouble wrapping my head around the logic, and was wondering if anyone else would volunteer to help me out.  I have long values (all in milliseconds) representing `timeSinceLastFrame` and `FPS` (which is the current amount of frames being looped per second).  I need this to occur in a `onFrame()` method which is called every update.

Answer (score 0):

More info would help. Can you call the method asynchronously? If so, you could use an event-based library like [Netty](http://netty.io) and set a timer.